# Find the missing combination from 2 columns based on ID

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to find the missing pair of numbers based on two columns so far I was successfully able to get the solution based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52728328/mysql-find-missing-combinations-between-two-columns) but it breaks whenever I add another column for the id. This is the modified query I have made

Schema

```
CREATE TABLE `your_table` (
  `id_session` int not null,
  `columnstart` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `columnend` varchar(8) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `your_table` (`id_session`,`columnstart`, `columnend`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(1, 1, 3),
(1, 2, 1),
(1, 2, 2),
(1, 2, 3),
(2, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 2),
(2, 1, 3),
(2, 2, 1),
(2, 3, 1);
```

Query

```
SELECT dt.columnstart, 
       dt.columnend 
FROM 
(
  SELECT t1.columnstart, t2.columnend FROM 
    (SELECT  columnstart FROM your_table where id_session = 2 group by columnstart) AS t1 
    CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT  columnend FROM your_table where id_session = 2 group by columnend) AS t2 
) AS dt 
LEFT JOIN your_table AS t3 
  ON t3.columnstart = dt.columnstart AND 
     t3.columnend = dt.columnend 
WHERE t3.columnstart IS NULL AND 
      t3.columnend IS NULL
```

Query result is

3 - 2 
3 - 3

Missing Pairs are missing pairs are `(2-2),(2-3),(3-2),(3-3)` (correct answer)
Please do note that: `1-3 != 3-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you are searching for missing combinations for a specific `id_session` (2 shown).

In that case you have to add `AND t3.id_session = 2` to the JOIN ON - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d8fcb5/5

Comment: I noticed that a combination rows of 1999 with 40 combinations so (40*40) will get me a result time of 5 mins, do you have any tips how to make this sql query more optimized?

Comment: @Shulz did you define any indexes in your real table? you need at least (id_session, columnstart) and (id_session, columnend)

Comment: Of course there are, indexes are not free, but they are quite crucial for DB performance. Not only selects, but updates and deletes too can use them, they have a "WHERE" clause too. The index needs to be written and updated too, so there is slight slowdown in all writes, on the other hand the speedup of the select should balance that easily. Indexes you don't need are a burden but indexes you need and use are the right thing.

Comment: What if `t3.id_session` is not being used. but rather the `event_name` that is linked to `id_session` from another `table`. Should I index the `event_name` instead of `id_session`?
For example: `(.....) FROM 
   two_balls 
  JOIN 
   two_balls_sessions ON two_balls.id_session= two_balls_sessions.id 
  WHERE 
   two_balls_sessions.event_name = 'MAY 31, 2021' `
(Sorry deleted the comment run out of time to edit)

Comment: One index can only cover columns from one table, so you may need both two_balls_sessions(two_balls_sessions) and two_balls(id_session).

Comment: Or similar, order matters, but multicolumn index can be used on a prefix too, so index on (a,b,c) is good for (a,b) and (a) too and you don't have to create all 3.